# C++ how to check the access to heap memory

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

I have the following question. I am not if it is possible and how.
I want understand when the code are using an memory address allocated in heap (for all type of objects built-in and user define).
For example:

```
char* p= new char[60];
strcpy(p,"home");  // statement A
```

There is a way to understand that "statement A" is using the address "p" allocated in heap ?
By redefining operator new, I can store the heap addresses but how to understand when some instructions are using them ?
I'd like to do this in transparent way for the user.

Thanks a lot

****** An example

```
char* p= new char[60];
delete [] p;
strcpy(p,"home");  // statement A
```

I want warning this invalid memory access.
To do this I must understand that strcpy are trying to access to the address p so i can perform some test on validity of p.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how to understand when some instructions are using them"? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Mat, I want understand when the program are using an address to read/write.

Comment: What do you mean by "understand" here? Or what don't you understand about statement A? Are there other sorts of statements you're not getting?

Comment: @Mat I'm not so sure the OP is talking about their understanding, but how to track access to memory adresses.

Comment: I added an example of what I'd like to do if possible. In free time, I am working a little project to perform statistic of use of heap and to check error (memory leak,invalid access memory,unitialized memory...)

Comment: In response to your edit: You can use smart pointers ( unique_ptr, shared_ptr, etc ), they gurantee that your memory is not deleted/freed as long as the smart_pointer still exists ( if used properly ). Would that solve your problem ?

Comment: Look up [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) tool, and [Address Sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) provided byClang and GCC.

Comment: I know valgrind and Intel Parallel Inspector to test the use of heap, but to learn I wanted to try this excercize

Answer (score 2):

See this: http://www.hboehm.info/gc/gcdescr.html 
It's a transparent garbage collector for C/C++. It keeps track of what pointers exist referencing a memory location in the way you describe:

> *At each collection, the collector marks all objects that are possibly reachable from pointer variables. Since it cannot generally tell where
>   pointer variables are located, it scans the following root segments
>   for pointers:*
>
> *The registers. Depending on the architecture, this may be done using assembly code, or by calling a setjmp-like function which saves
>   register contents on the stack. The stack(s). In the case of a
>   single-threaded application, on most platforms this is done by
>   scanning the memory between (an approximation of) the current stack
>   pointer and GC_stackbottom. (For Itanium, the register stack scanned
>   separately.) The GC_stackbottom variable is set in a highly
>   platform-specific way depending on the appropriate configuration
>   information in gcconfig.h. Note that the currently active stack needs
>   to be scanned carefully, since callee-save registers of client code
>   may appear inside collector stack frames, which may change during the
>   mark process. This is addressed by scanning some sections of the stack
>   "eagerly", effectively capturing a snapshot at one point in time.*
>
> *Static data region(s). In the simplest case, this is the region between DATASTART and DATAEND, as defined in gcconfig.h. However, in
>   most cases, this will also involve static data regions associated with
>   dynamic libraries. These are identified by the mostly
>   platform-specific code in dyn_load.c.*
>
> *The marker maintains an explicit stack of memory regions that are known to be accessible, but that have not yet been searched for
>   contained pointers. Each stack entry contains the starting address of
>   the block to be scanned, as well as a descriptor of the block. If no
>   layout information is available for the block, then the descriptor is
>   simply a length. (For other possibilities, see gc_mark.h.)*

As you can imagine, you have to really roll your sleeves up and do some extremely low-level hacks to manage this, and it's an expensive thing to scan memory like this so I don't think you can do this for safety reasons against dangling pointers.

I would recommend not trying to do this so transparently. Have users obtain *handles* to your objects like smart pointers and it'll become so much easier to impose garbage collection or safety against dangling pointers or whatever you like. C++ excels at those kinds of semi-transparent solutions where you can create objects that feel like pointers and offer the same operators but do whatever more you want on top.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make sense. Strcpy considers the pointer to point to valid memory, so you do not need to know anything special here. If you want to assert that the memory is valid use a class which takes care of that. Then you can always know that the memory is valid.

In this case std::string would be the right choise, elsewise std::vector or std::shared_ptr.